# Article the/a Which one is correct?

Tags: articles

Please give an explanation.
And you can give a link to the extended use of articles?
I just do not understand why in this case the article "the" is put, if this noun is singular, then the article "a" should be used, as it is written in the rules.

> Сan you get the meaning?

or

> Сan you get a meaning?

Comment: Both *the* and *a* are used for singular nouns. Please explain what rule you are referring to—we can't answer without knowing *why* you think it should be *a*.

Comment: Those both sound very unnatural to a native speaker. We don’t “get” “meanings”.

Comment: @tchrist - I've found 600 000 results for "get the meaning" on Google Books

Comment: @CowperKettle Now try for *understand*.

Comment: They can both be correct? in the first example, we know what is being said so put "the", and in the second we do not know what is being said, so "a". Am I right?

Comment: Could you tell us the context in which you'd like to use that sentence along with its intended meaning?

Comment: I saw it on YouTube, where a student was asked to explain the meaning of the word freeze.

Comment: @userr2684291and she said: can you get the meaning?

Comment: If she asked whether you got ***the*** meaning, she's implying *there is one single unambiguous meaning to be got*. If she asked whether you got ***a*** meaning, that would imply there are *several possible meanings* (any one of which you might "get").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, definite article THE is used when the speaker or writer believes that the listener or reader exactly knows what is referred to. The meaning is something specific. Do you get at THE meaning? Hence THE

But one can use an indefinite article if the word has multiple meanings/ implications. Take for example the word, CREDIT. It has different meanings. It may mean deposit, loan, Faith, honour and many more. In that case One may as well pertinently ask, " Can you get a meaning of CREDIT? It has so many meanings. Hence, "A".